# Redirect subdirectory to root subdirectory without changing url PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

`https://example.com/app1`

This is my subdirectory and it has one index.html file running on apache server.

I need to redirect all the requests to this directory like `https://example.com/app1/*` to `https://example.com/app1` without changing the URL.

If user access to `https://example.com/app1/test` it should be redirected to `https://example.com/app1` but URL should remain same as 
`https://example.com/app1/test`

Comment: Hello. What have you tried so far and where did you fail?

Comment: Hi, My problem is when someone launches to the URL my index.html script make sense of the URL and it should convey the information according to the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ index.php [nc,qsa]`

This one worked for me.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `public_html/. htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^app1/((?!index\.html).+)$  /app1/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: It is redirecting to home page and changing URL

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: My index.html code is in example.com/app. If the user launches example.com/app/something then my script needs to sense the URL and it should communicate with the database.